# Can Macbook Pro 13 drive Apple Cinema Display on full resolution?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, cinema-display

I have mid 2012 Macbook Pro with Core i7/HD4000 and 8GB RAM onboard (MD102 model). I am considering using an external display - to get better experience from graphics software (amateur Photoshop usage) and home entertainment (movies mostly).

Even though the Apple Cinema Display is quite expensive, it seems to fit my needs. But having read about issues with the Retina MacBooks displaying graphics properly, I'm worried if I could use a Cinema Display 27" with full resolution (same as Retina MacBook's) without additional issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the MBP and rMBP do 2560x1600 on an external monitor.  The 27" ACD only does 2560x1440 so it will not max out the full resolution capability of either laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. I use a Macbook 13" mid 2012 with Cinema Display.

Comment: And did you notice any problems with displaying? What kind of software do you use on a regular basis?